# How can I auto increment a value whenever a member is mentioned in a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on('message', async function(message) {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.includes('!reps')) {

        let usname = message.mentions.users.first().username;
        let usId = message.mentions.users.first().id;
        message.channel.send('Calculating ' + usname + `'s reps`);

            let repsChannel = client.channels.cache.get('66518878191720806');
            let sbChannel = client.channels.cache.get('66503449499402200');

            let chData = await repsChannel.messages.fetch( {limit:100}).catch(err => console.log(err));
            let mentamt = chData.filter(chData => chData.mentions.members.has(usId))
                let amts = mentamt.size
                console.log(amts)
```

This portion gives me the first 100 lines to check through and it seems to work, however, after including the While loop to check through the next 100 lines, I cant make it return the total sum

```
            while(chData.size === 100) {
                let lastKeyId = chData.lastKey();
                chData = await repsChannel.messages.fetch( {limit:100, before: lastKeyId }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                let tvalue = chData.filter(chData => chData.mentions.members.has(usId)
                let tamt = 0

        }
        sbChannel.send('> '+ usname +' has '+ amts);
    }
});
```

I want to auto increment the value of `tamt` whenever a member has been mentioned in a message.
The main purpose of this is to calculate the total number of times a member has been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using `async-await` in for loop, you can achieve it easily.

```js
const delay = () =>
  new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, 300, new Date());
  });

(async function () {
  async function page(count) {
    const result = await delay();
    // Do your work here
    return `Page ${count}:: ${result}`;
  }
  const chunkSize = 100;
  const pageCount = Math.floor(1121/chunkSize) + 1 
  for (let pageNum = 0; pageNum < pageCount; pageNum++) {
    const data = await page(pageNum);
    console.log(data)
  }
})();
```